# How to set a template with wp_insert_post

Tags: php, templates, rest-api, api

I'm trying to set my template to the Elementor Canvas when using wp_insert_post but it isn't working. It is creating the new page fine but not using the canvas. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
"action": "create_post",
"post_author": "<authorID>",
"post_content": "<post content>",
"post_title": "Leave us a Review",
"post_status": "publish",
"post_type": "page",
"comment_status": "closed",
"post_name": "<post-name>",
"page_template": "elementor_canvas"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can check this code  I am able to work with this

```
function cutom_function() {

    $new_page_id = wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_title'     => 'PKB',
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'post_name'      => 'pkb',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status'    => 'closed',
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_author'    => get_user_by( 'id', 1 )->user_id,
        'menu_order'     => 0,
        // Assign page template
        'page_template'  => 'pratik.php'
    ) );
```

Comment: Thanks, that code looks quite similar to mine, can you see any difference in mine that would cause the template to not set? My template name is definitely correct.